# Mark elements in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would like to group elements in my GUI. They are all in the same canvas, so they are not grouped visually. Some of them I want to move and some of them I want to shrink.

As I implement the animation in C# and not XAML I would like to know, if it is possible to mark the elements with a boolean or something similar in order to check its value when choosing the appropriate animation.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Almost anything is possible!  It may not be sensible, though, depending on the specifics of your project.  Have you tried your idea yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are doing the animation in code-behind you can use pretty much any way you want to attach this extra boolean to the objects.

As a simple approach, you can use [`FrameworkElement.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) on each of the elements to put your extra data in. But there's a million other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to associate extra data with the controls to flag them for animations, I would suggest using an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

In general I would suggest evaluating the objects themselves to determine how to animate them, but in some cases meta data is required. Attached properties fits this need perfectly.

Define a static class:

```
public static class AnimationType
{
   public static bool GetShrink(DependencyObject obj)
   {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(ShrinkProperty);
   }

   public static void SetShrink(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
   {
      obj.SetValue(ShrinkProperty, value);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty ShrinkProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Shrink", typeof(bool), typeof(AnchoredBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

When you go to animate, call `AnimationType.GetShrink(myControl);` and test the boolean return to see how to animate the control.